# Approximation for $(1-\frac1{2\sqrt{n}})(1+(1-\frac1{2\sqrt{n-1}}))(1+\dots)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics, approximation

Denote

$$M_i = \prod_{n=i}^K\left(1-\frac1{2\sqrt{n}}\right).$$

What could be a method of estimation of

$$\sum_{i=1}^K M_i$$
with regard to the value of $K$? It is not even of interest to find the precise explicit expression. It could be an approximate behavior with $K\rightarrow\infty$. Does it converge, diverge or decrease?

*My attempts:*

I've succeeded to find approximate behaviour of $M_1$ via Euler–Maclaurin formula for $\ln(M_1)$.

$$M_1 \sim \exp\left(-0.5\sqrt{K}\right)\sqrt[4]{\frac{1}{\sqrt{K}K-0.5K}}$$

But, it is not clear how to use it either intuitively to solve the problem.

**Edit.**

The question was deleted for some time, nevertheless [Did](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/6179/did) make a solution, which is accessible [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2154316/bounded-distance-generating-function).